# How to get the list of nodes running for my spark job in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to run a Pyspark Script in Databricks where that Databricks Cluster is being used by many users including me...

So my question here is, will I be able to obtain (or) is there a way to get the list of spark worker nodes of the databricks cluster with their ID that is running for my PySpark Script through script (or) code.

In that way, I can know how many spark worker nodes are being consumed for my Job from that databricks cluster which is being used by multiple users.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Try using the Spark UI...?

Comment: But, Spark UI will have LOG for the entire cluster, not for my specific job right!?

Comment: I think there are info for each job id, not sure...